# Динамическое изменение Navigation Bar в UITabBarViewContoller

Tags: swift

У меня есть Tab View Controller с тремя вкладками. Моя задача состоит в том, что бы на каждой вкладке содержимое Navigation Bar-а изменялось. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под изменялся? Цвет фона/title/еще чего?

Comment: @Vandrj, допустим, в обычном View Controller в Navigation Bar можно помещать любые объекты. Кнопки, контейнеры, даже WebView, а дальше, путем скрытия или отображения контейнеров, изменять содержимое Navigation Bar. Мне нужно реализовать что-то подобное

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать метод tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) и, в зависимости от того, какой таб пользователь выбрал, менять содержимое NavigationBar, например:

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    print("Did select item")
    let button = UIBarButtonItem()
    let index = (tabBar.items?.index(of: item))!
    switch index {
    case 0:
        button.title = "Button1"

    case 1:
        button.title = "Button2"

    case 2:
        button.title = "Button3"

    default:
        break
    }

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button
}
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую, спасибо!

Comment: Сработало! Странно, что Xcode не позволяет вручную настраивать Navigation Bar в UITabBarController... Спасибо Вам!

Comment: Обращайтесь :-)